# Using Karnaugh maps to construct and simplify Boolean expressions

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to construct a circuit based on K-maps (see picture) - and I must do so only through *two-level logic* (excluding inverters).

[image: K-Maps]

Some of the K-maps naturally came out in two-level logic, but a few of them didn't. I used AND-OR logic by taking 1's. For the ones that exceeded two logic levels I got the following:

1st column, 4th map: $$AB+ \bar{A}\bar{B}C+A\bar{B}\bar{C}$$
This would require 3 AND gates (first level), a two-input OR (second level; we don't have three-input OR gates), and another two-input OR (third level).

2nd column, 2nd map: $$ A\bar{B}\bar{C}+ABC+\bar{A}B\bar{C}$$
Again, this would be over two levels.

2nd column, 3rd map: $$\bar{A}\bar{B}\bar{C}+AC+AB\bar{C}$$
Once more, over two levels.

Is there a way to reduce these expressions further? I thought the point of using K-maps was to get Boolean expressions in their simplest form; well at least most of the time.

Comment: So you have 3 input NAND/AND gates, but not 3 input OR/NOR gates? A K-map will give you a minimal SOP representation, but that's often not optimal for implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately no, we don't have three-input OR/NOR gates. Is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: But you have 3 input NAND/AND gates?

Comment: That's correct. Why?

Comment: We're using TTL logic by the way, not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: So just use those (the 3 input NAND/AND). There are ways of transforming AND gates to OR gates, given enough inverting dots.

Comment: Wouldn't that introduce much more than two levels of logic?

Comment: Also, just to clarify. You're talking about DeMorgan's theorem right? Isn't that for NAND -> Negative OR, NOR-> Negative AND?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about DeMorgan's theorem, but it's not for *just* NOR/NAND. The theorem describes a transformation of operators and logic inversions, resulting in the ability to convert between (N)AND and (N)OR. Assuming that you get inverted inputs for free, all of these can be accomplished with 4 NAND gates.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. I'm not sure if just the input inversions are free, or if all inversions are. I'll work it out regardless. Out of curiosity, is there any other way to get this expression down to two physical gates?

Comment: Output inversions are free as long as you get to pick from AND/NAND. Getting the expression down to two physical gates? Very unlikely with your more complicated expressions without building custom gates. If you allow custom gates, you could get it down to 1 gate, but it'd have to be *really* worth it. Two separate 7400 series ICs should be easy, but that's probably not what you meant.

Comment: Woops, actually I meant three gates. I get what you mean though. I was just wondering why my professor specifically said we were not allowed to exceed three gates. Do you mean free in the sense that since I can choose between AND/NAND that inverting is essentially picking the right one? I thought you meant according to the arbitrary rule made by my professor that inverters are free, meaning they don't count as a logic level.

Comment: Your question appears rather incoherent to me. What do you mean by "two-level logic"? K-maps will give you minimal two-level (but not minimal multi-level) logic solution using all NANDs or all NORs, but [you know that already](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153883/converting-karnaugh-maps-to-boolean-expressions). Also it's unclear which function you're trying to minimize. Please consult [a standard reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_optimization#References_and_further_reading) and use terminology people can relate to... or at least explain what you mean with yours.

Comment: Based on some passing remarks on not having some circuits, I'm guessing you are talking about using *only circuits with a fan-in of two*. This in addition to the two-level limit or is the fan-in of two the only limitation? Are you also limited to some types of gates? In general, the problem of multi-level minimization of a function using only some fixed set of gates (and negation) is [rather hard](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/publications/2013/iwls13_npn.pdf), well to do by hand anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If we allow exor gates then here is a solution.

1st col 4th map: (A exor C) + AB

2nd col 2nd map: (A exor B) + ABC

2nd col 3rd map: !(A exor C) + AB, alternatively (A exnor C) + AB

Edit:

Take col 1 map 4 for example. The first two columns have a pattern I recognize as an  XOR gate. First row is 01, second row is 10. Now I look at the boxes with '1', A changes when jumping between the two. Look for another variable that is also changing; in this case it is C. A and C are either 01 or 10 in the '1' boxes: that is the characteristics of an XOR gate. Only two '1' remain in the map and they are grouped into the term AB.

Now col 2 map 2: Here are two groups that will work for an XOR gate; col 1 & 4, and col 3 & 4. The first group produces an XOR gate, the second an XNOR gate. In the XNOR gate, both inputs must be equal to produce a '1' on the output.

Finally col 2 map 3. This map looks like col 1 map 4, except the XOR pattern is reversed. That means we use an XNOR gate instead of the XOR in the first map, or we add an inverter to the XOR output.

By the way, regarding your equation for col 1 map 4, notice that the two bottom corners both have '1'. You can group them to produce the term A!C, reducing your third term to two variables.

Comment: How do you get this? I'm looking to simplify other expressions so I'm interested in learning how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- NOTs do not count.
- 3-input ANDs and NANDs are valid.
- 2-input ORs and NORs.

You have some errors in your equations. Edges of K-maps loop around and you can reuse terms.

The correct answer for 1st column, 4th kmap is:

$$AB + \bar A \bar B C + A\bar C$$

Take DeMorgan's: Invert expression, change signs, invert terms.

$$ \overline {\overline {AB} • \overline {\bar A \bar B C} • \overline {A\bar C)}}$$

Two 2-input NANDs + two 3-input NANDs. Two levels.

The correct answer for 2nd column, 3rd kmap is:

$$\bar A \bar B \bar C + AC + AB$$

Take DeMorgan's:

$$\overline { \overline {\bar A \bar B \bar C} • \overline {AC} • \overline {AB}}$$

Again, two 2-input NANDs + two 3-input NANDs. Two levels.

I believe this is enough for you to get concept.  Your instructor is giving you a problem which cannot be done unless you think outside the AND-OR box.  AND-OR becomes NAND-NAND.